# Digest value obtained programmatically different from soapUI?

Tags: python, xml, soap, sha, digest

I would like to sign a xml document  to send it to a soap web service. 
To begin, I am trying to sign a simple node like this:

`<test xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-F4821D01E882FF4507149477187940483">
    truc
</test>`

The digest value of the test element is “pdB9Sx1CJ6Cj2z/FoqamVKkjxZ8= ».

Here is a simple python code to compute the digest value:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.ext import c14n
import base64
import hashlib
doc = minidom.parse('file2.xml')
canonical_xml = c14n.Canonicalize(doc)
print (canonical_xml)
print base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(canonical_xml).digest())
print (" ".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in canonical_xml))
```

The node «test«  is in the file named ‘file2.xml’.

To test the soap request, I create it with SoapUI but the digest value of this node is different.
I don’t understand why the digest value from SOAPUI is different. 
I have «ONNdniHbKnsMddcMR8rUuPWxbgw= ».

Here is a part from the document xml generated by SoapUI:

```xml
<ds:Reference URI="#id-F4821D01E882FF4507149477187940483">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv urn" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>ONNdniHbKnsMddcMR8rUuPWxbgw=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

Can someone explain to me why those digest values are different?

Comment: In the Python code you're getting the digest of the `Canonicalized` doc, but the  SOAPUI may be using the actual one (or something else).

Comment: I thought that also so I tried without canonicalization, without and with whitespace, new line... But it doesn't work.

Comment: No one can help me ?